# Clean way to conditionally unmarshal JSON to struct

Tags: json, go, google-cloud-firestore

I'm sending requests to a JSON API, and it either returns an error...

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Document not found.",
    "status": "NOT_FOUND"
  }
}
```

or the data.

```
{
  "name": "projectname",
  "fields": {
    "userId": {
      "stringValue": "erw9384rjidfge"
    }
  },
  "createTime": "2018-06-28T00:52:25.638791Z",
  "updateTime": "2018-06-28T00:52:25.638791Z"
}
```

Here are the corresponding structs

```
type HttpError struct {
    Code    int    `json:"code"`
    Message string `json:"message"`
    Status  string `json:"status"`
}

type Document struct {
    Name   string `json:"name"`
    Fields struct {
        UserID struct {
            StringValue string `json:"stringValue"`
        } `json:"userId"`
    } `json:"fields"`
    CreateTime time.Time `json:"createTime"`
    UpdateTime time.Time `json:"updateTime"`
}
```

Once I get the response, how do I cleanly/concisely unmarshal to the correct struct? I've seen a lot of ugly solutions (maybe Go's fault instead of the writers).

```
func getDocument() {
    resp, _ := httpClient.Get("example.com")
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    bodyBytes, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

    var data map[string]interface{}
    // How to unmarshal to either HttpError or Document??
    err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(bodyBytes), &data)

}
```

By the way, I can't use the Go Firestore client library because reasons.

Comment: Unmarshall to one format then to the other if the first did not succeed. Or unmarshall to `map[string]string` or `map[string]interface{}` first and infer.

Comment: @zerkms is correct. Also, the server should provide appropriate http status codes along with the error json. If it is providing the codes then you can only unmarshal the json to document if the `resp.StatusCode` is 200 and unmarshal to `httpError` otherwise.

Comment: @SiddharthShishulkar That's a good idea, I think i'll do that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an struct type inside your unmarshal method; with pointers to establish what's been unmarshalled.

**Note:** This code assumes there is no overlap of top level json keys... error / name / fields / etc.

```
type outer struct {
    *HttpError `json:"error"`
    *Document
}

var out outer

if err := json.Unmarshal(bodyBytes, &out); err != nil {
    // error handling
}

if out.HttpErr != nil {
    // handle error json case
}

// Here you can use out.Document, probably worth check if it is nil first.
```

[Runnable example](https://play.golang.org/p/xYbWH24fv7q)